# Wordpress posts displaying the same content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple custom page template with a simple loop that displays links to posts of the same category ID=11.
However, the problem is that although the links are working correctly, all posts are displaying the same content (the content of the first post).  I can't work out why this is.  Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Here is the loop on the custom page template

```
  <?php 
          $args = array('cat' => 11);
          $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

          if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
          while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
          $category_posts->the_post();
        ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        <?php
          endwhile;
          else: 
          // no posts.
          endif;
        ?>
```

And here is what I have on single.php

```
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: update your question: first - what `$category_posts->have_posts()` return. second: post your `$category_posts->the_post();` function

Answer (score 0):

You should call the_post() in single.php before doing anything else.

Try this:

```
<?php the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Leave your other code alone. It looks like it should be working as expected.

Comment: OK single.php now looks like:  <?php the_post(); ?> <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1><?php the_content(); ?> Both posts are displaying content of post #2 (I have only written two posts).  If I remove  <?php the_post(); ?>  they both display the content on post #1...  Is the loop ok?

Comment: It's working in my test installation. There must be something else going on with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out through some trial and error.  I had a list of post titles in the sidebar and needed to use wp_reset_query.

Answer (score 0):

In single.php use the following code to get the content and title.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    the_title();    // For post title
    the_content();  //For post content

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in your custom page,  i used wp_reset_postdata();

```
<?php 
      $args = array('cat' => 11);
      $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

      if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
      while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
      $category_posts->the_post();
    ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <?php
      endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata();
      else: 
      // no posts.
      endif;
    ?>
```

And on single.php use this

```
<?php
```

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

```
the_title();    // For post title
the_content();  //For post content
```

endwhile;
?>